# Looking for large multidimensional datasets

Tags: data-request, visualization

Where can I find large sample files with multidimensional data?

I'm interesting in both categorical and mostly quantitative data.

Anything from spatio-temporal weather simulations to health studies or preferably anything with 20 variables.

I want to try different visualization tools and I need data to test them.

Comment: I've also found this https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html   but without much details. And this  http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/ftp.html  but I'm not able to download from there.

Comment: I've also found http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/mondrian/
http://davis.wpi.edu/xmdv/datasets.html

Answer (score 3):

You can search through the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html) by the # of Attributes.

For example, the [Arrhythmia dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Arrhythmia) has 279 attributes.